# Convert dictionary values into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

This could be answered somewhere but I can't seem to work any of the solutions with what I have...

I have a following dictionary data_dict:

```
data_dict:
{'df_0':
     Name    Role       Location
0    Gina    Assistance    NY
1    Jake    Officer       Brooklyn
2    Boyle   Detective     99
3    Scully  Assistance    NY
4    Diaz    Officer       Brooklyn
 'df_1':     
     Name    Role       Location          
5    Hitchcock Detective     99
6    Amy    Assistance    NY
7    Terry    Officer       Brooklyn
 'df_2':  
     Name    Role       Location
7    Terry    Officer       Brooklyn
8    Holt   Detective     99
9    Judy   Assistance    NY
10   Adrian Officer       Brooklyn
}
```

In the dictionary above **df_0, df_1, df_2** are the keys for **data_dict** and each of the keys is a dataframe that contains columns **Name, Role, Location**

The output I am seeking is a **master_df** that combines values from data_dict keys and outputs the following results:

```
master_df:
     Name    Role       Location
0    Gina    Assistance    NY
1    Jake    Officer       Brooklyn
2    Boyle   Detective     99
3    Scully  Assistance    NY
4    Diaz    Officer       Brooklyn
5    Hitchcock Detective     99
6    Amy    Assistance    NY
7    Terry    Officer       Brooklyn
8    Holt   Detective     99
9    Judy   Assistance    NY
10   Adrian Officer       Brooklyn
```

Any help / guidance is appreciated!!

Comment: Are the values for the dictionary pandas dataframe?

Comment: @davidkunio yes type(data_dict['df_0']) returns pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you're trying to do. Can you be clarify things?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) function, something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
master = pd.concat (data_dict.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

You an `concat` and then `drop_duplicates()`:

```
master_df = pd.concat([df_0, df_1, df_2]).drop_duplicates()
```

EDIT: Reading more closely... you are doing this from a dictionary... so try dejdej's answer. You may have to drop duplicates, but I didn't test.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all!

For my purpose I found this solution to output what I needed:

```
output = pd.DataFrame()
for k in data_dict:
    output = output.append(data_dict[k], ignore_index=True)
```

Thank you everyone for your time and suggestions!